# check to see if all values inside an array is a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a way to check if an array only contains numbers. 
For example

```
var a = [1,2,3,4] should pass and give true boolean

whereas var b = [1,3,4,'a'] should give false
```

I tried forEach() function as

```
a.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    if(!isNaN(item)) {
        array.unshift("-");
    }
});  //console.log of this will give array a = ["-","-","-","-", 1,2,3,4]
```

but since, forEach() iterates through every index in the array, and since every item for var a is a number, it unshifts to array every item it iterates. I need a way to only unshift "-" once if the whole array value is a number.

I also tried to do with test()

```
var checkNum = /[0-9]/;
console.log(checkNum.test(a)) //this gives true 

console.log(checkNum.test(b)) // this also gives true since I believe test     
                              //only checks if it contains digits not every 
                              //value is a digit.
```

Comment: no doubt i'm missing something here but why not set a boolean to false. Then scan the array and test there is one thing that is not a number. If so then set a boolean to true.  Test if the boolean is still false and if so, then the array is all numbers. And then you want to insert a '-' into the beginning of the array since the boolean tested to still be false.. I guess it'd be that basic unless you only want to do it with a High order function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest is to use the `every` function of `Array`:

```
var res = array.every(function(element) {return typeof element === 'number';});
```

Comment: Nice - I made the same with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#every). I didn't knew, that JS has `every` already.

Comment: Be aware that `every()` isn't available in some older browsers (IE 8, etc.). The MDN has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill) you can use when `every()` isn't built-in.

Comment: the latest stable release for ie8 is 4 years old. ms released 3 new major versions and a new browser in the mean time. people cannot refuse to upgrade their browsers, and at the same time complain of the lack of compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var a = arr.reduce(function(result, val) {
   return result && typeof val === 'number';
}, true);
```

```js
function areNumbers(arr) {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(arr) + ':')
  return arr.reduce(function(result, val) {
    return result && typeof val === 'number';
  }, true);
}

document.write(areNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4]) + '<br>');
document.write(areNumbers([1, 2, 3, '4']) + '<br>');
```

Comment: `reduce` still iterates the whole array, it's better to use `every`

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit how can `every` not iterate through the whole array.. though yeah 'every' looks like it's more built for the job.

Comment: see the accepted answer, if the first value in the array is not a number, iteration will stop. See the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 0):

`var filteredList = a.filter(function(item){ return !isNaN(+item) });`

the + sign at the beginning will attempt to convert the whatever the item is to a number, if it can it will not filter it out for example:

`var numbers = +"123"`

`console.log(numbers) //will print out 123 as numbers not as a string`